# How do I undo the installation of an extension? Getting "Base table or view not found" for "eav_attribute" table

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, attributes, extensions

I tried to install the ["Amazon Payments"](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pay-with-amazon-for-magento-1.html) extension in my Magento 1 community edition, and the installation didn't go through. Now when I try to access my Magento site, I get an error. The error is the following:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:478:"Error in file: "/mysite/mag/app/code/community/Amazon/Payments/sql/payments_setup/install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'carving_magento.mageav_attribute' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main`.*, `additional`.* FROM `mageav_attribute` AS `main`
 INNER JOIN `magcatalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional` ON main.attribute_id = additional.attribute_id WHERE (main.attribute_code = :id) AND (main.entity_type_id = :entity_type_id)";i:1;s:932:"#0 /mysite/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /mysite/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.4.0')
#2 /mysite/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.4.0')
#3 /mysite/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /mysite/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /mysite/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /mysite/mag/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /mysite/mag/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/mag/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:14:"/mag/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

From the error, I notice that it's looking for a database table that I don't have:

```
Table 'carving_magento.mageav_attribute' doesn't exist
```

NOTE: All my tables are prefixed with "mag" so the real table is "eav_attribute" which also doesn't exist in my DB

[You can view the full "install-0.1.0.php" script from Amazon Payments here.](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-plugin/blob/master/app/code/community/Amazon/Payments/sql/payments_setup/install-0.1.0.php)

**How do I undo the installation of this extension?**

**Or should my next step be trying to create the "eav_attribute" table as described [here](https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-eav_attribute-table-in-magento/)?**

I restored my database back to yesterday's database using my host (Dreamhost)'s control panel. This didn't help; it is still trying to install the extension when I try to get to my magento admin control panel.

There are also instructions from Amazon Payments on how to install the extension [here](https://payments.amazon.com/help/201828680).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this extension, go to
`magento_folder/app/etc/modules`

And look for something like `amazon_payments.xml`.

Open this file and change the line:
`<active>true</active>`

To: `<active>false</active>`

This way you can acces your website again.